# Most efficient way to query 1 of 4 large Access tables based on condition (using VBA module)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sharepoint

For the past couple weeks I've been working on a very unconventional solution to a problem for my job. I'm almost there, but I need to know the most efficient way to do the last step. I will dumb it down so I don't have to write an essay describing the insane nature of the problem I've been working on.

I have four large local tables in MS Access with a total of over 500,000 records.
Each table represents a different type of product.
The productID for table1 always starts with "9"
The productID for table2 always starts with "8"
The productID for table3 always starts with "4"
The productID for table4 always starts with "3"
I have a vba procedure written that does exactly what I need it to do except I have it querying information using only table1 thus far. Basically, a user inputs a productID and the procedure searches the table for that record and sends the information to a sharepoint list. Speed of execution is HIGHLY important in my situation. So, what is the fastest way to have it run? Should I write a statement that says "If the ID starts with 9 then search this table, ElseIF ..... and so on." Or, should I combine all the tables into one and not have it look at the first digit of the ID?

I know this sounds like a simple issue but trust me, this is a wild over simplification of the real issue and it would take 2,000 words to explain how ridiculous it actually is; I'm not kidding. However, I am fairly confident that the answer to the above question will give me all the information I need to finish this project successfully. I have come so far and all I have left is to figure out the most efficient way to apply it to the 3 other tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Access VBA has a timer class: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/timer-function-46da243c-2570-4950-a818-6d6934bf584a  Create a new database Import some mock data from excell or generate the mock data with vba.   Then loop through the data both ways a few thousand times each and compare.  I bet split tables will be faster but not absolutely sure.

Comment: Why don't you check it out. It would take less time than waiting for assumptions from us, as no definitive answer can be given without the data. My guess is, however, that checking the first digit and searching only one table will be the quickest method.

Comment: I came here before testing it because im off work for the day and tomorrow I can check to see what advice has been offered. This is also difficult to test because I have it running on a time interval so it’s sensitive to bad code. Yesterday I spent all day testing the previous component and dealing with crashes so I could get to where I am now. I’m hoping to avoid some of that tomorrow by starting off with the best-bet method.

Comment: Just make sure that productID has an index. Everything else is pretty much irrelevant. If it is the primary key, then all data should be in one table, saving lots of hassle. If it must stay in different tables, then of course do the If/Then first.

Answer (score 0):

As the tables are local, use the `Seek` method which is extremely fast:

[Recordset.Seek method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-seek-method-dao?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

If the tables were linked, you could still using `Seek` by opening the backend database. This is an example:

```vb
Function SeekTable()

  Const cstrTable As String = "tblValue01"
  Const cstrAttached As String = ";DATABASE="
  
  Dim wks As Workspace
  Dim dbs As Database
  Dim tdf As TableDef
  Dim rst As Recordset
  
  Dim strConnect As String
  Dim strTablename As String
  
  Set wks = DBEngine(0)
  Set dbs = wks(0)
  Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(cstrTable)
  
  strConnect = tdf.Connect
  strTablename = tdf.SourceTableName
  Set tdf = Nothing
  
  If InStr(1, strConnect, cstrAttached, vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then
    strConnect = Mid(strConnect, Len(cstrAttached) + 1)
    ' Open database shared and read-only.
    Set dbs = wks.OpenDatabase(strConnect, False, True)
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTablename)
    '
    ' Perform Seek operation. Example.
    rst.Index = "ID"
    rst.Seek "=", 10010
    Debug.Print rst!Value
    '
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
  End If
 
  dbs.Close
  Set dbs = Nothing
  Set wks = Nothing
  
End Function
```